# How to show dynamically the right element according to Route path?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I'm learning React framework and I'm stuck on a question. I have this array which contains pieces of information about some templates I built.

```
const template = \[
{
title: 'firstPortfolio',
url: 'first_portfolio',
id: 1,
img: require('../templates-images/firstPortfolio.png')
},
{
title: 'leadershipEvent',
url: 'leadership_event',
id: 2,
img: require('../templates-images/leadership-event.png')
},
{
title: 'digimedia',
url: 'digimedia',
id: 3,
img: require('../templates-images/digimedia.png')
},
{
title: 'arsha',
url: 'arsha',
id: 4,
img: require('../templates-images/arsha.png')
}
\];

export default template;
```

I've imported it in App.js (I know that the code makes a little pity and does not reflect the logic on which React is based, I'm new):

```
import './App.css';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import HomePage from './pages/Homepage';
import Portfolio from './pages/Portfolio';
import Template from './pages/Template';
import template from './assets/js/templates';

import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  const [menuBtn, setMenuBtn] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {

    const menuBtn = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
    const lineOne = document.getElementById('lineOne');
    const lineTwo = document.getElementById('lineTwo');
    const lineThree = document.getElementById('lineThree');

    const lineOneAnimation = [
      { width: '30px', top: '18px', transform: 'rotate(0deg)' },
      { width: '30px', top: '26px', transform: 'rotate(45deg)' }
    ];

    const lineTwoAnimation = [
      { width: '20px', top: '26px' },
      { width: '0' }
    ];

    const lineThreeAnimation = [
      { width: '10px', top: '34px', transform: 'rotate(0deg)' },
      { width: '30px', top: '26px', transform: 'rotate(-45deg)' }
    ];

    const menuAnimationTiming = {
      duration: 200,
      iterations: 1,
      fill: 'both'
    };

    menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (menuBtn.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          lineOne.animate(lineOneAnimation, menuAnimationTiming);
        }, 200);
        lineTwo.animate(lineTwoAnimation, menuAnimationTiming);
        setTimeout(function () {
          lineThree.animate(lineThreeAnimation, menuAnimationTiming);
        }, 200);
      } else {
        lineOne.animate(lineOneAnimation, menuAnimationTiming).reverse();
        lineTwo.animate(lineTwoAnimation, menuAnimationTiming).reverse();
        lineThree.animate(lineThreeAnimation, menuAnimationTiming).reverse();
      }
    });

  })

  const templateRoutePath = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
      return `/portfolio/${template[i].title}`;
    }
  }

  const pathGit = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
      return `https://andrea-mazza.github.io/template/${template[i].url}/`;
    }
  }

  // const templateKey = function () {
  //   for (let i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
  //     return `${template[i].id}`;
  //   }
  // }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className='container-fluid'>
        <Navbar expand="lg">
          <Container fluid>
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">FreeAttitude</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle onClick={setMenuBtn} aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" id="menuBtn">
              <span id="lineOne" className="line"></span>
              <span id="lineTwo" className="line"></span>
              <span id="lineThree" className="line"></span>
            </Navbar.Toggle>
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbbar-nav">
              <Nav className="menu-items">
                <Link to="/" className="nav-item">Home</Link>
                <Link to="/portfolio" className="nav-item">Portfolio</Link>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
      </header>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
        <Route path={`/portfolio/:templateTitle`} element={<Template gitPath={pathGit.apply()} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Route Component in question is the last one, which render the Template component. The Template Component's code is this:

```
import template from "../assets/js/templates";

function Template(props) {

    const title = function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
            return `${template[i].title}`
        }
    }

    return (
        <iframe src={props.gitPath} title={title.apply()} />
    );
}

export default Template;
```

**What am I trying to do?** I'd like to show the Template Component whit the right gitPath props, according to the path of the Route Component.

**What is the problem?** This work but only the first <iframe> is shown, for all the Route that starts with '/portfolio/'. For example: If I type: '/portfolio/firstPortfolio' I can see an iframe element that shows the template I previously built and which is stored on GitHub. However, if I type: '/portfolio/leadershipEvent/' I see again an iframe that shows firstPortfolio project instead of an iframe for the leadershipEvent project.

I have attached some pictures for clarity:

1. If I click on firstPortfolio image
   [image]

I actually see the project with the correct URL:
[image]

2. But, if i click on the leadershipEvent img:
   [image]

URL is correct but the src iframe's attribute points again to the firstPortfolio github's url

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the `Template` `title` function?  I'm certain it's not doing what you think.  Regardless, you want to use the `useParams` hook to get the template title out of the url

Comment: I'll go see what you suggested, thank you! At first I hadn't thought of writing it and an error occurred. Honestly I don't remember exactly, but it was something like: "every iframe should have an unique title attribute". However I have tried to remove this function now and no errors have occurred so I decided to permanently remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question. To dynamically create a route component and display the right project based on the URL I wrote this code in the `App.js` file:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
    {/* The JSX below is used to dynamically create Route Component for each template */}
    {
      template.map(element => {
        return (
          <Route path={`/portfolio/${element.title}`} key={element.id} element={<Template gitPath={`https://andrea-mazza.github.io/template/${element.url}/`} />} />
        );
      })
    }
  </Routes>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The `title` function simply returns the `template` array's first element's `title` property. It doesn't iterate the entire array or do anything else.

```
const title = function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
    return `${template[i].title}`
  }
}
```

There is a similar issue with `templateRoutePath` and `pathGit`.

## Solution

The `Template` component should use the `useParams` hook to access the `templateTitle` route path parameter ***then*** search the `templates` array for the matching element to access the `title` and `url` properties.

Example:

App

```
<Route
  path="/portfolio/:templateTitle"
  element={<Template />}
/>
```

Template

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import templates from "../assets/js/templates";

function Template() {
  const { templateTitle } = useParams();

  const template = templates.find(template => template.title === templateTitle);

  if (!template) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <iframe
      src={`https://andrea-mazza.github.io/template/${template.url}`}
      title={template.title}
    />
  );
}
```